Ist das eine Vermischung von Präteritum und Perfekt?
3. Klasse Grundschule: Es soll ausschließlich Präteritum verwendet werden.
Das Kind schreibt:

Nachdem sie sich den Regenbogen angeschaut hatte …

„Angeschaut hatten“ sei laut Lehrerin nicht richtig, weil es nicht Präteritum ist. Richtig sei:

Nachdem sie sich den Regenbogen anschauten …

Aber ist das nicht eine andere Bedeutung? „Angeschaut hatten“ meint doch eine abgeschlossene Handlung, oder?

Falls der Satz vorgegeben ist, ist die Aufgabe ungünstig (um nicht zu sagen: ungeschickt) gestellt, weil die verwendete Zeitform Plusquamperfekt ("sie hatte angeschaut") hier tatsächlich grammatisch korrekt ist, da Plusquamperfekt die Vorzeitigkeit einer Handlung anzeigt. Daher wäre es verwirrend, in der Aufgabenstellung in diesem Satz Präteritum zu verlangen.
Die Lehrerin hat jedoch insofern recht, dass hier nicht Präteritum verwendet wurde und der Satz damit nicht im Sinne der Aufgabenstellung (wenngleich grammatisch korrekt) gebildet wurde.

Der Satz war nicht vorgegeben.  Es war eine Bildgeschichte zu schreiben.

Es ist Plusquamperfekt, aber Plusquamperfekt und Präteritum gehören zusammen. Es ist beides für Erzählungen gedacht. So wie Perfekt und Präsens zusammengehören, und beides für die Wirklichkeit gedacht ist. Oder so wie Futur II und Futur I zusammengehören, und beides für Annahmen gedacht ist. Das eine ist die Perfekt-Variante des anderen und markiert jeweils die abgeschlossene Handlung. Oder die Vergangenheit des anderen, wenn man es mit einfacheren Worten ausdrücken will.
Nun kannst du sagen, diese Lehrerin ist so eine Obergescheite, die einem Kind, das eigentlich nichts falsch gemacht hat, irgendwas anstreichen will. Denn das Adverb „nachdem“ spricht ja für eine abgeschlossene Handlung, also ein Perfekt-Tempus.
Allerdings muss man im Deutschen nicht jeden Nebensatz, der mit „Nachdem“ beginnt, mit einem Perfekt-Tempus markieren. Man kann das auch lassen, und damit in den Grenzen so einer Aufgabe bleiben:

Nachdem sie sich darüber klar waren, dass die Lehrerin Mist erzählte, hakten sie die Sache ab und beschäftigten sich mit etwas Schönerem.

In dem Beispiel sind Mist erzählen und klar darüber sein nicht mit einem Perfekt-Tempus markiert. Es handelt sich also um Dauerzustände.

Es ist tatsächlich nicht einfach, wenn man Kindern Präteritum beibringen möchte, sie nicht gleich mit Feinheiten und Ausnahmen zu verwirren.
Aber das Sprachgefühl der Schülerin hat doch gestimmt, oder?

Ja, sie hat das komplett richtig gemacht.

Im vorliegenden Fall war offensichtlich nicht das Sprachgefühl in Bezug auf die korrekte Verwendung der Zeiten Gegenstand der Aufgabe, sondern das Wissen, was das Präteritum ist im Unterschied zu anderen Zeitformen. Und im Hinblick darauf entspricht der Satz tatsächlich nicht komplett der Aufgabenstellung.

Es ist keineswegs so, dass im Deutschen Perfekt für abgeschlossene und Präteritum für nicht abgeschlossene Handlungen verwendet wird. Im Deutschen kommt es für die Zeitform ausschließlich auf den Zeitpunkt an. Der sog. Aspekt, also ob eine Handlung abgeschlossen ist oder noch im Gange ist, spielt keine oder eine zumindest völlig untergeordnete Rolle. Darin unterscheidet sich das Deutsche von vielen anderen Sprachen.

Die Perfekt-Zeiten sind auch im Deutschen für in der Vergangenheit abgeschlossene Handlungen gedacht. Handlungen, die in der Vergangenheit beginnen und andauern, werden mit einer nicht-Perfekt-Zeitform markiert. Das ist der große Unterschied z.B. zum Englischen, wo es speziell für diesen Zweck z.B. das Present Perfect Progressive gibt.


Der Satz war nicht vorgegeben. Es war eine Bildgeschichte zu schreiben.(aus Kommentar)

Das scheint mir ein Fall zu sein, in dem die sprachliche Kompetenz der Schülerin weit über das Niveau der Aufgabenstellung hinaus geht.
Ein simpler Satz, der der Aufgabenstellung entspricht, wäre

Sie schaute sich den Regenbogen an. Dann ...

In unteren Klassenstufen werden Geschichten oft auf diese Weise erzählt und die Sätze mit dann ..., danach ... usw. verbunden.
Hier ist die Schülerin offenbar über das nachdem gestolpert, hat dann vollkommen richtig Plusquamperfekt benutzt und möglicherweise gar nicht bemerkt, dass hatte hier eben nicht Präteritum bedeutet.
Ich würde so etwas nie als falsch bezeichnen, sondern eher die sprachliche Kompetenz hervorheben, die sich hier zeigt und das Beispiel vielleicht als Brücke zum nächsten Thema benutzen (guter Ausdruck, Erzählstil, wann ist Präteritum nicht die beste Wahl, wie hängen Präteritum und Plusquamperfekt zusammen  ...).
